# jQuery: changing the available options in a list based on the selected option

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="studentinst" size="6">
    <option value="1">First Installment</option>
    <option value="2">Second Installment</option>
    <option value="3">Third Installment</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth Installment</option>
    <option value="5">Fifth Installment</option>
    <option value="6">Sixth Installment</option>
</select>
```

If I select 4, it should only display the first 4 options and the rest should be hidden. 
Desired output:

```
  First Installment
  Second Installment  
  Third Installment
  Fourth Installment
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

see sample [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/9/)  check this link... for loop doesn't work over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#studentinst').change(function() {
    if ($('option:selected').val() == 4) {

        $("#studentinst option[value=5]").remove();
        $("#studentinst option[value=6]").remove();
    }
    else {
        if ($('#studentinst option[value=5]').val() == null)

        $('<option>').text('Fifth Installment').val(5).appendTo($('#studentinst'));

        if ($('#studentinst option[value=6]').val() == null) $('<option>').text('Sixth Installment').val(6).appendTo($('#studentinst'));
    }
});
```

If hide doesn't work as expected, this is another way to do it.

[see sample](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/6/)

Comment: i is used as string in that code. it should be like this: $('#studentinst option[value='+i+']').remove();     http://jsfiddle.net/PQ7GF/11/

Comment: have selected your answer and ticked it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, there may be a shorter way to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#studentinst').change(function(){
        var selectedIndex = $('#studentinst :selected').index();            
        $('#studentinst option').each(function(){
            if($(this).index() > selectedIndex){
                $(this).hide(); //or you can use .remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This method is based on the options index but you could use .val() instead if .index() if you are basing the removal on the values